# Suppose that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and there is a number $p \in [a,b]$ so that $f(p) = q$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and there is a number $p \in [a,b]$ so that $f(p) = q$. Show that:

1. The set {$x \;|\; f(x) = q$} is closed.
2. The set {$x\;|\;f(x) < q$} is open.
3. Suppose further that $a,b$, and $p$ are numbers so that $f(a) = f(b), a < p < b,  f(p)\neq f(a)$ and f is differentiable on (a,b). Show that there exists $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that $f'(c_1) > 0$ and $f'(c_2) < 0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. You'll find that you will receive a positive response to questions like this if you share your progress to date.

Comment: The condition $f(p)=q$ is not needed.

Comment: I know for the first question I must assume the set is not closed. Thus, there will be two cases with $f(p)>q$ and $f(p)<q$ with p as a limit point of the set, but not in the set. I just need some guidance now where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important equivalent (and more general) definition of continuity: a map $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the domain for every open $U$ in the range.  The same applies to closed sets.  So now 1 and 2 come down to characterizing the sets $\{q\}$ and $(-\infty,q).$

As for 3, apply Rolle's theorem.